# Calculation of two fields in ASP.NET (Visual Basic)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, field

I have two money fields in a SQL database called TotalClaimed and PartialSettlementAmountRecd.

They are declared as Decimals like so:

```
Public PartialSettlementAmountRecd As Decimal
Public TotalClaimed As Decimal
```

They both output the repsective amounts perfectly. I need to do a calculation on them, by subtracting PartialSettlementAmountRecd from TotalClaimed. I have tried the following, but it just outputs a random number, not the amount I require.

```
Dim NewSettAmount As Decimal =  (ClaimDetail.TotalClaimed) - (ClaimDetail.PartialSettlementAmountRecd)
Response.Write("New Settlement Amount: £" & NewSettAmount)
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it be:

```
Dim NewSettAmount As Decimal = (ClaimDetail.TotalClaimed) - (ClaimDetail.PartialSettlementAmountRecd)
```

<>

Comment: Yes, I mistyped the calculation in here, your way is how I have it in my application.

Comment: post more code in your question then. This is a simple substraction, nothing here points to a problem of getting a random output...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do a calculation on them, by subtracting PartialSettlementAmountRecd from TotalClaimed

```
(ClaimDetail.PartialSettlementAmountRecd) - (ClaimDetail.TotalClaimed)
```

Aren't you doing the opposite of what you want?  Aren't you subtracting TotalClaimed From PartialSettlementAmountRecd?

Comment: I mistyped the calculation in here, your way is how I have it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise. The random figures I was getting were due to somebody entering a huge number in the Total Claimed field in the database whilst I was testing without telling me! The code actually works now with sensible figures.